# Does a hormone PTSH exist?

Tags: endocrinology

It's known that a hormone called TSH (thyroid stimulate hormone) does exist  and it's secreted in the pituitary gland. But my question is about a hormone which secreted from the pituitary gland too but it stimulates the **para**thyroid glands. 
I am asking it because I read [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7420044) and I'm not sure how the science refers to it currently.

Comment: It seems to exist but I cannot find anything definite myself yet other than it is mentioned in [Beria, et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jad.2018.04.002). *"All  patients  underwent  12 structured  sessions  of  group  cognitive-behavioral  therapy  for  PD  (17)  and  had their  blood  collected  at  baseline  to  assess  fasting  glucose,  complete  blood count,  thyroid  stimulating  hormone,  **parathyroid  stimulating  hormone**..."*

Answer (score 4):

In short: It seems, there is not enough evidence to say that parathyroid-stimulating hormone secreted from the pituitary gland exists in humans.

**A) Parathyroid Stimulating Hormone (PTH)**

Some texts use the term **parathyroid-stimulating hormone with the acronym PTH** or in a way that suggests they actually meant parathyroid hormone.

[Journal of Cell Science (2008)](https://jcs.biologists.org/content/joces/121/21/3581.full.pdf?with-ds=yes):

> ...and parathyroid hormone-related peptide receptor (PTH1R), whose
>   stimulation by **parathyroid stimulating hormone (PTH)** increases the
>   intracellular levels of cAMP, IP3, DAG and Ca2+...

[Respiratory subtype of panic disorder: Can serum phosphate levels be a possible outcome to group cognitive-behavior therapy? (Journal of Affective Disorders, 2018)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165032717323893?via%3Dihub):

> All patients underwent 12 structured sessions of group
>   cognitive-behavioral therapy for PD (Otto and Deveney, 2005) and had
>   their blood collected at baseline to assess fasting glucose, complete
>   blood count, thyroid stimulating hormone, **parathyroid stimulating
>   hormone**, ionized calcium, creatinine and phosphate levels.

[Chronic Mucocutaneous Candidiasis Workup (Emedicine, 2017)](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1091928-workup):

> Other endocrine screening tests that may be considered include
>   follicle-stimulating hormone, luteinizing hormone, prolactin,
>   testosterone, **parathyroid-stimulating hormone**, calcium, phosphate,
>   magnesium, and short synacthen test.

[Dermatology Online Journal (2014)](https://escholarship.org/content/qt4kq2z97b/qt4kq2z97b.pdf):

> According to current guidelines for high risk patients (i.e. those
>   that are genetically confirmed to have MEN-1), annual laboratory
>   studies to include calcium, **parathyroid stimulating hormone**,
>   prolactin, gastrin...

*^^From this [NIDDK article](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/endocrine-diseases/multiple-endocrine-neoplasia-type-1), it is clear that parathyroid hormone is meant above.*

---

**B) Parathyroid Stimulating Hormone (PSH)**

I've found a single text that mentions **parathyroid stimulating hormone with the acronym PSH**, in which they clearly suggest it is secreted from the pituitary gland and stimulates the release of parathyroid hormone.

[Cranial Endocrine Glands Represented at Intertragic Notch (ScienceDirect, 2014)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/intertragic-notch):

> 103.e Parathyrotrophin Hormones (PSH, Parathyroid-Stimulating Hormone)    [IT 2] Location: Found on the most central part of wall of
>   intertragic notch, below LM_9.
>
> Function: The parathyroid pituitary hormone PSH regulates parathormone
>   release by the parathyroid gland. This point facilitates calcium
>   metabolism and reduces muscle tetanus.

**C)** I haven't found any text in which **parathyroid-stimulating hormone** in *humans* would be mentioned with the acronym **PTSH** (like in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7420044) linked from the question, which mentions PTSH in *cows*).

Comment: Great answer Jan.

Answer (score 2):

The pituitary does not have a direct effect on the parathyroid glands.

> The parathyroid gland and adrenal medulla are not controlled by the
>   pituitary but play important roles in calcium metabolism and the
>   adrenergic (sympathetic nervous system) function respectively. Source:
>   [Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0263931914001598)

Although they are located close together, the thyroid and parathyroid glands work independently.

The role of the parathyroid glands is to regulate blood calcium levels. They do this by secreting [parathyroid hormone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parathyroid_hormone) (PTH) when calcium levels fall, in a negative feedback system.

PTH has the following effects:

- Increases release of calcium from bone (by increasing osteoclasts activity)
- Reduces calcium losses in the kidneys
- Increase calcium absorption in the gut

As a result, calcium levels in the blood will be corrected to normal levels.

The hormone [calcitonin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcitonin) has the opposite effect of PTH. It is actually secreted by the thyroid gland itself in response to high calcium levels.

Here is a diagram summarising the role of PTH ([source](http://what-when-how.com/acp-medicine/diseases-of-calcium-metabolism-and-metabolic-bone-disease-part-1/)):

[image: Effects of parathyroid hormone]

Here is a basic diagram showing interplaynof parathyroid hormone and calcitonin ([source](http://biology.reachingfordreams.com/biology/endocrine-system/13-thyroid-and-parathyroid-gland-hormons)):

[image: Parathyroid and calcitonin]

The study you mention relates to cattle and is almost 40 years old. There has been nothing that I can find in human research to suggest the presence of a clinically significant parathyroid-stimulating hormone.

Comment: What is your take on Beria et al. I referenced in my previous comment?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes I looked at that article and I’m really not sure. I cannot find anything else on PTSH anywhere, nor am I familiar with it from any of my own practice. As that paper relates primarily to mental health (i.e. not an endocrinology paper), I suppose it might be a mistake - I wonder if they meant thyroid stimulating hormone (TSH) or parathyroid hormone (PTH). As they were looking at calcium and phosphate, I think PTH is more likely.

Comment: Perhaps a clinical observation helps: Patients with hypopituitarism are faced with multiple and severe health problems, but hypocalcemia (which would result from lacking stimulation of the parathyroid glands) isn't typical (with the exception of rare autoimmune destruction of both pituitary and parathyroid).